# I can't override the "handleMethodArgumentNotValid" from the "ResponseEntityExceptionHandler" class

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

This is my code and I'm trying to override the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method. However, VSCode doesn't let me override the method

[image: The class that I am trying to override the function]

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ContactNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleContactNotFoundException(ContactNotFoundException ex) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Even if I write the whole function myself (with the same parameter and signature), it still doesn't work. I don't get any error, it just doesn't let me override it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did and what didn't work as expected?